# Jakarta EE module, component and container

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm reading the [Jakarta EE tutorial](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/toc.html) and i'm finding the words component, module, and container all over the place but i haven't found any formal definition for them. So, i would like to know what is component, module, and container?

Answer (score 0):

components:

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/platform-spec-8.html#application-components
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnabb/index.html

modules:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/packaging001.html

containers:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/overview005.html

So in short: your application consists of 1 or more modules (.jar/.war/.ear archives). Each module consists of components (client side/web components/business components). The components run inside a container (EJBs -> EJB Container/ JSF, Servlets, ... -> Web Container/ Application client and Applet containers -> Client side).